# Ubuntu 20.04 Keeps on Showing "Prohibited" error, ALT+F2 shows its "^@" Key being stuck

Tags: keyboard

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS dual boot Windows 10 for my work laptop, one day, suddenly theres a forbidden / prohibited icon shows up as this image [The error pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLEQ3.jpg).

I first tried to log in to my Windows OS, there is 0 problem and everything runs smoothly. then I tried to use online keyboard checker web app, I can't see any key being pressed repeatedly so I thought this might be a software issue, after a few minutes looking around the forum, some people pointed out it might be a media key being stuck. I don't have any media key, I tried to check the keyboard configuration and there is no media key mapped (all disabled). Then, I tried to use ALT+F2 to see if there any key being pressed repeatedly and then there it is. ["^@" key is being pressed repeatedly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bum3Q.png)

I tried to search what the ^@ key is and apparently it is null (CMIIW) I figured out this might be a software / driver issue. So I tried to update my Windows' driver but it didn't fixed my error

Is there any way for me to disable the ^@ key or fix this error?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I figured this is most likely a hardware problem, after booting into windows I came into notice that one of the USB (not sure which) is continuously being unrecognized, replaced my laptop with the exact same model then swapped the ssd. configured the storage option in bios then everything returns to normal